# Pass a DOM event to custom form validator in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to validate a form using the reactive approach. I am using the file input to take a file from the user. I have defined a custom validator that allows the user to upload a file on certain conditions. While trying to do so, I am getting an error. The validator does not receive the event as a whole but rather only the path of the file something like `C:\fakepath\abc.xlsx`. I want to pass the DOM event so that I can handle all the properties of files like type, size etc.

Here's my code:

> file.validator.ts

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateFile(control: AbstractControl) : 
{ [key: string]: boolean } | null {
    const value = control.value;

    if (!value) {
        return null;
    }

    return value.length < 0 && value.files[0].type !== '.xlsx' && value.files[0].size > 5000000
    ? { invalidFile: true } : null;

}
```

> sheet.component.ts

```
constructor(
private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
private alertService: AlertService
) {
    this.sheetForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    sheetType: ['Select Sheet Type', [Validators.required]],
    sheetUpload: [null, [Validators.required, ValidateFile]],
    sheetDescription: [
      null,
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(10),
        Validators.maxLength(100),
      ],
    ],
  });
}
```

> sheet.component.html

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="sheet-upload">Upload Sheet: </label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input
      id="sheet-upload"
      type="file"
      (change)="handleFileInput($event)"
      formControlName="sheetUpload"
      accept=".xlsx"
    />
    <small
      id="custom-error-message"
      *ngIf="
        (sheetForm.get('sheetUpload').dirty ||
          sheetForm.get('sheetUpload').touched) &&
        sheetForm.get('sheetUpload').invalid
      "
    >
      The file size exceeds 5 MB or isn't a valid excel type. Please
      upload again.
    </small>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way but it works

- Create a directive to attach the native element to form control
- On validation get the file from the native element in the validator
- And also to use formControlName you need to assign a formGroup in the parent element (ignore if included in some other parent element)

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName]',
})
export class NativeElementInjectorDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    (this.control.control as any).nativeElement = this.el.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

file.validator.ts

```js
export function ValidateFile(control: any): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
  const value = control.value;
  const file = control?.nativeElement?.files[0];

  if (!value) {
    return null;
  }

  return value.length < 0 || file.type !== 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' || file.size > 5000000
    ? { invalidFile: true }
    : null;
}
```

sheet.component.html

```html
<div class="input-group" [formGroup]="sheetForm">
  <label for="sheet-upload">Upload Sheet: </label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <input
    id="sheet-upload"
    type="file"
    formControlName="sheetUpload"
    accept=".xlsx"
  />
  <small
    id="custom-error-message"
    *ngIf="
      (sheetForm.get('sheetUpload').dirty ||
        sheetForm.get('sheetUpload').touched) &&
      sheetForm.get('sheetUpload').invalid
    "
  >
    The file size exceeds 5 MB or isn't a valid excel type. Please upload again.
  </small>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: if you console log file in the validator can you see the file details?

Comment: The code isn't throwing any error. However, the value for the file variable is undefined.

Comment: have you added NativeElementInjectorDirective to the module declarations list?

Comment: Hi, I didn't add the directive in the declarations list. Upon doing so, I am getting an error.

`ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular v10. I have resolved this issue by removing `(change)="handleFileInput($event)"`. However, I am not getting an error when I try to upload file of any other type.

Comment: change the logic in the return statement to || conditions instead of &&, I have updated the answer, and you have set accept=".xlsx", so you should not be able to upload any other file types

Answer (score 0):

You can get reference to input element and use it in validator.

```
<input #sheetUpload ...>

@ViewChild('sheetUpload') fileInput: HTMLInputElement;

private ValidateFile(): ValidatorFn {
return (control) => {
  const value = control.value;

  if (!value || !this.fileInput) {
    return null;
  }

  const file = this.fileInput.files[0];

  return value.length < 0 && file.type !== '.xlsx' && file.size > 5000000
    ? { invalidFile: file.name }
    : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a cleaner way of doing it.